# Binance now updating my btc balance

Tags: blockchain, xrp-reserve

I transferred some ltc coins from gdx to binance. Binance shows that I have the transferred amount in my profile. But btc balance for trading is always shown as 0.000000. How much time will it take to reflect. I am trying to buy xrp and unable to buy because of that. what may be the issue?

Comment: did you convert your litecoins to btc?